# Is it possible to store Video 'WebM' or' MOV' in react browser storage? If so how?

Tags: reactjs, browser, local-storage, storage, webm

I was searching for ways to store Video files in a browser using `React JS` not react native.  Could not find anything so I don't think it's possible.  Browser storage is limited to 5mb.  Was wondering if there were a different way for storage.  File System API doesn't seem to work for me or there are no live examples available to see if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: You can use indexedDB which would offer you more store than local storage. But there also should be some limitations for storing blob type data because it's new feature.  I suggest you to not store any files in browser as it will persist on only client browser.